# trying to reuse a ResultSet obtained from database

Tags: java, jcombobox, resultset

```
  Driver dr = new Driver();
   myConn = dr.connectDB();
   myStmt =  myConn.prepareCall("{call spViewUsers()}");
   myStmt.execute();

   myRS = myStmt.getResultSet(); 
   while (myRS.next()){
       String name = myRS.getString("userID");
       cbUser.addItem(name);
```

This is a simple login window where the username is populated into a `JComboBox` (`cbUser`). The code above works, but now I'm wondering if I can re-use the `ResultSet` to obtain the corresponding password when the `cbUser` value is changed, or do I have to store the `ResultSet` fields into an array. It'd be nice if I could get a specific row based on the value of a column (not the column's label). For example, let's say this is my table:

```
userID  userPassword
-------------------
admin   123456
guest   qwerty
random  abcd
```

I want to get the value `qwerty` when `guest` is selected in `cbUser`.

**Is it possible?** Thanks!

Comment: why not use a map with a key value as `userID` and `password` and whenever you need them just `map.get("guest")`

Comment: @singhakash I'm exploring Java. I know there are other options, but the reason I ask is because I want to know if there is any way to get this value from the ResultSet since it already contains the data from the database.

Comment: so thats what I said use a map

Comment: @singhakash alright then. So I'm assuming I can't do this with a ResultSet Thanks!

Comment: yes while iterating over the resiltset just put values in `map.put("userId","password")`